# Extract function parameters and default values from any function

Tags: r, function, arguments

Is there a way to extract the parameters and their respective default values of any given function from **outside** the function?

For example, given:

```
myfunc <- function(a, b = 1) { print(c(a, b)) }
```

I'm looking for some function that will return:

```
list(a = NULL, b = 1)
```

or some variation thereof.

Comment: Why do you use `NULL` for argument "a"? What would be result for `function(a, b = 1, c = NULL)`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are looking for `formals()`.

```
formals(myfunc)
# $a
#
#
# $b
# [1] 1
```

If you needed `NULL` for `a`, you could do some checking.  `a` will be of the "name" class and empty.

```
lapply(formals(myfunc), function(x) if(is.name(x) & !nzchar(x)) NULL else x)
# $a
# NULL
#
# $b
# [1] 1
```

Comment: Could use `missing(x)` to detect what you are calling "empty". Returns logical. I'm guessing you tried `is.null` first and got an error, but `missing` does not attempt to evaluate its argument.

Comment: @42- - How do you mean?  If I do `lapply(formals(myfunc), function(x) missing(x))` I get FALSE for both.  `is.null()` also returns FALSE for both because `a` is not actually null, it's a name `""`

Comment: `myfunc <- function(a,b=1){print(missing(a))}; myfunc(); #TRUE` Agreed it's not NULL. `missing` has meaning inside a function and I don't think that passing formals one by one with `lapply` would give the same information. If you change `missing` to `is.null` and run it, you instead get an error instead of TRUE.

Comment: OP is trying to do this from outside the function.