# How to test if particular function has argument of given name?

Tags: r

How to test in R if particular function has argument of given name?

An illustration of what I need:

```
f <- function (a, b, c)
{
    1
}

fun_iam_lookin_for(f, "b") # should return TRUE
fun_iam_lookin_for(f, "d") # should return FALSE
```

Comment: Look at  `formals`, see more at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36533368/extract-function-parameters-and-default-values-from-any-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```r
f <- function (a, b, c)
{
    1
}

fun_iam_lookin_for <- function(f, x) x %in% names(formals(f))
fun_iam_lookin_for(f, "b") # should return TRUE
#> [1] TRUE
fun_iam_lookin_for(f, "d") # should return FALSE
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, awesome! :-)