# Circular definition of function

Tags: r, function

I read a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61641924/how-to-test-if-particular-function-has-argument-of-given-name) on function arguments which included the `formals` function and I was eager to find out how the function is defined. I used `base:::formals` and it gives:

```
function (fun = sys.function(sys.parent())) 
{
    if (is.character(fun)) 
    fun <- get(fun, mode = "function", envir = parent.frame())
.Internal(formals(fun))
}
```

To me it is unclear how this works because inside the definition of the `formals` function the `formals` function is used. That seems paradox to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.Internal(formals(fun))` calls an internal R function, coded in C. It just happens that this C internal function is also named `formals`.
So it does not call the same function, just an internal one that happens to be internally named "formals".

cf https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Internal.html