# How to check if a particular argument in a function has a certain value

Tags: r, function

I am looking for a tweak to this question:

[How to test if particular function has argument of given name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61641924/how-to-test-if-particular-function-has-argument-of-given-name)

This checks if a function has a certain formal argument.

```
# my function: 

f <- function (a, b, c)
{
    1
}

# This function will check if **any** arguments in f are equal to "x":

check_if_any_argument_is_certain_value <- function(f, x) {
x %in% names(formals(f))
}

fun_iam_lookin_for(f, "b") # should return TRUE
#> [1] TRUE
fun_iam_lookin_for(f, "d") # should return FALSE
#> [1] FALSE
```

However, how would I adapt this to check if **only the first argument** is equal to a certain value?

Desired output:

```
check_if_first_argument_is_certain_value <- function(f, x) 
{code - to be determined}

check_if_first_argument_is_certain_value(f, "a") # returns TRUE
check_if_first_argument_is_certain_value(f, "b") # returns FALSE
```

Comment: `identical(x, names(formals(f))[1])`

Comment: "This will check if the function "f" has any of its arguments taking a certain value." No, it doesn't. It checks if a function has a certain formal argument.