# Extract predefined values for an argument of a function

Tags: r, function, arguments

I would like to extract a set of values for a specific argument of a function.

To demonstrate the problem, I have a function

```
 myFUN <- function (x, y, method = c("top", "down", "left", "right")) {}
```

and I would like to extract the values "top", "down", "left", "right" from the argument *'method'*.

I have been able to extract the argument with `args` or `match.call`

```
as.list(args(myFUN))$method
```

which returns, literally the string `c("top", "down", "left", "right")`.

How do I get now all the values between the double quotes `"`? Can I parse somehow the string `c("top", "down", "left", "right")` into a variable as a vector, to get `"top", "down", "left", "right"`?

or is there a better way of extracting the argument from a function?

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36533368/680068

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eval` to get the vector.

```
eval(formals(myFUN)$method)
#eval(as.list(args(myFUN))$method) #Alternative
#[1] "top"   "down"  "left"  "right"
```